# Which of the followings are correct:

Tags: general-topology

Which of the followings are correct:

[image]

I know that the set in D is closed and hence D is false.

Comment: if you know that D is false, i hope you can clearly see what C would be...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: Right you are. It's a straight line and so can be proved similarly to be closed.

Comment: For A, I suggest looking at how $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb R$ are related to one another.

Comment: good. keep going.. try for A,

$\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. What about its compliment.

Comment: For (B), write down the definition of nowhere dense, and reword it in terms of $X\setminus \overline{A}$. Now note that $X\setminus A$ contains $X\setminus\overline{A}$

Comment: @SritiMallick : by seeing two users giving same hint at a time, i think you should see how concrete this example is :)

Comment: $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb R$ is the standard textbook example of a dense set with dense complement, because by the time you get to introductory topology, you are most likely very familiar with it. It helps with the intuition of what "dense" means. Then a year or so later comes the Zarisky topology, and that intuition more or less has to be built up from scratch again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counterexample to (A): $X=\mathbb R$, $A=\mathbb Q$

(B): Let $U$ be any nonempty open set. $U\not\subseteq A$ because $A$ is nowhere dense. Therefore $U\cap (X\setminus A)\ne \emptyset$, i.e. $X\setminus A$ is dense.

(C): $\mathbb R\times \{0\}$ is a closed proper subset, hence not dense.

(D): The diagonal is a closed (because $\mathbb R$ is Hausdorff) proper subset, hence not dense.